# How to get the index of a listview item by its text

Tags: c#, forms, listview

I'm trying to get the index of an item by its text in a listview.

For example, I have a list view which contains items: "item1", "item2", etc.

I've tried to get the index of "item2" like this:

```
MessageBox.Show(listView1.Items.IndexOf("item2");
```

But it's not working:

> can't convert from int to string / can't convert from string to System.windows.forms.listviewItem

How can I fix it?

Comment: When you say it's is not working, what do you mean? Are you getting any error? Does the index you get is wrong? Thanks

Comment: I get Errors: can't convert from int to string / can't convert from string to System.windows.forms.listviewItem

Comment: Please make a try with using `listView1.Items.IndexOf("item2").ToString()` and let me know. Thanks !

Comment: Thanks for helping..but I still get:
Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [ListView.FindItemWithText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.finditemwithtext) method does what you want:

```
var item = listView1.FindItemWithText("item2");

if (item != null)
{
    MessageBox.Show(listView1.Items.IndexOf(item).ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Let us have a `ListView`, whose ID is `listView1`. In order we get the items that are in this list view, we have to use the following code:

```
listView1.Items
```

*What's the type of* `listView1.Items`?

The type of `listView1.Items` is `ListViewItemCollection`.

For more documentation on this, please have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection(v=vs.110).aspx).

*What's the type of the objects that are stored in this collection,* `listView1.Items`?

The type of the objects that are stored in `listView1.Items` is `ListViewItem`.

For more documentation about this class, please have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Why doesn't `MessageBox.Show(listView1.Items.IndexOf("item2");` work*?

The reason why you get the error you posted on your comment is that method called `IndexOf` takes as a parameter an object of type `ListViewItem`, and you pass an object of type `string` as a parameter to this method.

Actually, as you can see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection.indexof%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the signature of the method called `IndexOf` is the following one:

```
 public int IndexOf(
    ListViewItem item
)
```

So in order you get the index of the item you want, you have to pass to the method called `IndexOf` a `ListViewItem`. For this reason I suggest you try the following code:

```
// Select the first ListViewItem of items, whose Text is item2
ListViewItem item = listView1.Items
                             .Cast<ListViewItem>()
                             .FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Text=="item2");

MessageBox.Show(listView1.Items.IndexOf(item).ToString());
```

Comment: Sorry..That's what I got
Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'string'

Comment: You are right, my fault. I am sorry. Please try the updated one now and let me know. Thanks

Comment: Ok, please give me a few minutes to figure out how we can overcome this. Thanks

Comment: @user3379482 please make a try with the updated code.